# How to get rid of /dev/loopN

Tags: usb, mount

On my Ubuntu 13.04 Lenovo notebook, I tried to create a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu 13.10 for a MacBook Air decided to go to Ubuntu too. The "Startmedienersteller" (sorry, German UI, may be start media creator in English) first failed several times but finally finished normally. Even then the USB stick does not boot on the MacBook Air (which the 13.04 version created on Windows machine did), but this is another story.

When I now look into "Sytemüberwachung" in the tab "file systems" I now find a bunch of new, 100% full, filesystems

```
/dev/loop0                    881M    881M     0  100% /tmp/tmp0hoyt9
/dev/loop1                    881M    881M     0  100% /tmp/tmpl2btns
/dev/loop2                    881M    881M     0  100% /tmp/tmpqk7r4b
/dev/loop3                    881M    881M     0  100% /tmp/tmpn_38uh
/dev/loop4                    881M    881M     0  100% /tmp/tmpre2ggl
/dev/loop5                    881M    881M     0  100% /tmp/tmpdm2dh8
```

mount tells me for each of these file systems

```
/home/bier/Downloads/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso on /tmp/tmpdm2dh8 type iso9660 (ro)
```

so I guess the filesystems will not really use up any recognizable disk space. Nevertheless they are very disturbing in the "Systemüberwachung" so I would like to get rid of them. But how to do this?

Comment: Try looking in fstab and removing their entries.

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: actually there is no entry in /etc/fstab for those /dev/loopN file systems...

Comment: @Novine `sudo apt-get autoremove` is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no more needed. It will not affect file systen mounts.

Comment: Worth a shot though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Startup disk creator" leaves with two devices being mounted: 1. the newly created stick, 2. the image (in my case `ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64+mac.iso`) from which the stick was created. The stick can be seen from the file manager and can be "ejected" from there. This was not the case with the image file. In the "Disks" application, however, the mountpoint *is* visible and can be unmounted.